# Web App Azure (version de prueba) y proyecto codeigniter

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, azure

Pues es mi primera vez usando Azure como host para un proyecto de codeigniter, pues decidí montarlo en esta plataforma ya que: 
1. Necesito conectarlo con una base de datos en SQLServer (De forma gratuita) para una presentacion rapida.
2. Desconozco de momento algún hosting que pueda hacerlo funcionar (Si tiene alguna sugerencia con gusto la revisare.)

Bueno dado que ya configure y subi mi proyecto a azure, pues configure mi routes.php, database.php, config.php y cree un archivo web.config, tal como sigue esta distribución de carpetas:

- root

  - myproject

    - application

      - config
      - database.php
      - routes.php
      - config.php
    - system
    - index.php
    - web.config

Resulta que la pagina tira un error 500.19, pero no tengo idea de donde pueda surgir.. revise mi web.config pero al parecer esta bien. De momento desconozco si me faltó algun otra configuracion, como dije apenas estoy empezando en azure y pues si me pueden dar algun tip o consejo les estaré muy agradecida..

Aca mi web.config:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
           <rule name="Index">
              <match url="^(.*)$" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
      </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```